# Getting error while parsing XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I am trying to parse a xml file using TouchXml for this. Unfortunately, I am getting error

Entity: line 1: parser error : **Start tag expected, '<' not found even when parsing sample** xml  that is definitely correct.

Code is:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SampleXml" ofType:@"xml"];

NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil]autorelease];

NSArray *nodes = NULL;

nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//nodeX" error:nil];

for(CXMLElement *node in nodes){
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    int counter;

    for(counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++){

        NSString * value = [[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if(value){
        [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[node childAtIndex:counter] name]];
        }}

    [item setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"id"] stringValue] forKey:@"id"];
    [result addObject:item];
    [item release];
}

NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
```

May it be a problem with touchXml class or am I doing something wrong? Please help.

Comment: Did you check the XML file in the first place?

Comment: Start which the simplest one:

    <? xml version="1.0" ?>
    <root />

And if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar thing before (not in objective c but in c#) when there were spaces or newlines before/between the start xml tag and other nodes. Strip out all whitespace and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I thought that problem may be with a xml file and although I have checked it out, I then tried to use a simple sample xml file found from internet, like this: <pigletlist>
<piglet id="1">
    <name>Nifnif</name>
</piglet>
<piglet id="2">
    <name>Nufnuf</name>
</piglet>
<piglet id="3">
    <name>Nafnaf</name>
</piglet>
</pigletlist> BUT RESULT WAS SAME

Comment: what line is throwing the error? "nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//nodeX" error:nil];
"?

Comment: I think that I know what part of the code is causing the problem. touchxml is now working properly, but problem is actually whit the data.  When I get the data from the server and Nslog it I see a long list of bytes, that means data is coming properly. But when I try to convert this data to a string, using NSUTF8StringEncoding the nslog output of the string is (null). When chosing [NSString defaultCStringEncoding], the output of the string is ˇ˛< and with ASCIIStringEncoding it is ÿþ<. Howeever if I ask [data length] I am getting 123180, which means that it is proper data, not only three chars

Comment: Okay heres a stab in the dark - what character encoding is being used to encode the xml? and is there a character encoding parameter/setting in the method you are using? You may want to investigate what 'codepage' the encoding is at both ends and make sure they match (i.e. windows will encode in codepage 1252 and if the receiving end is a different os it may expect it in a different one. HTH

Comment: reading your comment again I have about 90% certainty the codepage is the problem. The server side code that is BinaryFormatting the string must be told to encode using a codepage expected by your recieving unencode. see here for exmaple and possible codepages to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page

Answer (score 0):

Problem was actually with data encoding. Data from server was in unicode. I needed to convert it to utf8 and after that could parse data.

To convert data I firstly stored it in NSString(initWithData dataUsingEncoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding) and than created new NSData from string. But I am almostly certain that there is much easier method to convert data from one encoding to other without creating additional strings... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: actually I think that is probably the way to do it Olga. IMHO objective c is still not a fully mature language and still requires a LOT of work to make it developer friendly i.e. why is there not an operator overload for string + string? ... such a small fundemental operation and yet not available. The verbosity is also a bit of a running joke in my developer office